# Syntax error when giving column name with parameter substitution

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create an SQL statement in Python that adds a column with a specific name to a table, but I am getting the error you see in the tittle.

I'm currently using this code.

```
columnname = 'note'
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE my_table_name ADD COLUMN %s MEDIUMTEXT", (columnname,))
```

That should create a column in my_table_name named note but it gives me this error:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''note' MEDIUMTEXT' at line 1")

I know I should use normal string interpolation. But I want to keep adding columns like, column1 then column2 then column3 if the other ones are already storing data.

Comment: You can't use parameter substitution for column names. In this case you should just use normal string interpolation.

Comment: Same I answered to @O. Jones ----> But what if I am trying to add consecutive tables? Like: I store some (UNIQUE) data on column 1, then when I try to insert data again, if column1 is already storing some data I want to create column 2 and repeat that process so it should be columnname +=1 to add column1 after it column2 etc..

Comment: As already said. Use normal string interpolation but never accept column names from external source.

Comment: Not working. Same error using string interpolation. I dont know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use SQL "bind variables", also known as parameter substitution, for a column name. You Can't Do That™, You must specify column names (and table names) directly in your SQL statement.

Use normal string interpolation to construct your statements. Try something like this:

```
columnname = 'note'
cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE my_table_name ADD COLUMN {columname} MEDIUMTEXT")
```

Or if you're using old-timey Python 2, use this:

```
columnname = 'note'
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE my_table_name ADD COLUMN " + columname + " MEDIUMTEXT")
```

You can, obviously, do this in a loop of some kind.

(Careful:  adding columns to tables with many rows can be time consuming. And, adding columns to get around a UNIQUE index restriction is a very strange way to design a table.  Instead, maybe, use a column without a UNIQUE index.)

If your columname values come from an end user, you **must** validate them before you use them. Otherwise, cybercreeps.

[image: XKCD Johnny Drop Tables]

Comment: Hey, still not working, I used this: columnname = 'note'
cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE my_table_name ADD COLUMN {columname} MEDIUMTEXT") But Its not working. Error: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{columname} MEDIUMTEXT' at line 1")